# Conditionally create LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime based on parsed TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, datetime

Given a `DateTimeFormatter` defined as:

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append( ISO_LOCAL_DATE )
        .optionalStart().appendLiteral( ' ' ).optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart().appendLiteral( 'T' ).optionalEnd()
        .append( ISO_LOCAL_TIME )
        .optionalStart().appendLiteral( ' ' ).optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart().appendZoneOrOffsetId().optionalEnd()
        .toFormatter();
```

I'd like to conditionally create a `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` based on whether the parsing included a zone-id, an offset or neither.

So far I have:

```
    DATE_TIME.parse(
            text,
            (temporal) -> {
                // see if there is an offset
                final ZoneOffset offset = temporal.query( TemporalQueries.offset() );
                if ( offset != null ) {
                    return OffsetDateTime.from( temporal );
                }

                // see if there is a tz
                final ZoneId zoneId = temporal.query( TemporalQueries.zoneId() );
                if ( zoneId != null ) {
                    return ZonedDateTime.from( temporal );
                }

                // otherwise its a LocalDateTime
                return LocalDateTime.from( temporal );
            }
    );
```

What I have found though is that a zone-offset is never "recognized" - even if the text includes an offset, it is always reported as a zone-id.  E.g. given `"1999-12-31 12:59:59 +02:00"` I'd expect an `OffsetDateTime`.  However the `"+02:00"` is always parsed as a zone-id.  Ultimately it works given the reciprocity between zoned and offset.  But as a matter of (probably way over the top) correctness I'd like to treat these as `OffsetDateTime`.

Am I missing something to be able to make that distinction?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I do get an `OffsetDateTime` when trying to parse `1999-12-31 12:59:59 +02:00` using your code. I am using Java 9.0.4.

Comment: Out of curiosity, to what type are you assigning the result? `Temporal`?

Comment: @erickson `Temporal` would be a good choice. It’s more specific than `TemporalAccessor` (which I used in my “answer”, it sufficed for my needs there, even `Object` would have worked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer. Jacob G. already provided that. I’d just like to supplement.

### Workaround for Java 8

The `ZoneId` that you get from either `TemporalQueries.zone()` or`TemporalQueries.zoneId()` is a `ZoneOffset` when an offset has been parsed from the string. EDIT: `UTC+02:00` doesn’t come out as a `ZoneOffset`, but calling `normalized()` on the `ZoneId` converts it into one. Now the `instanceof` operator will tell you which you have got.

```
    for (String text : new String[] {
            "1999-12-31 12:59:59",
            "1999-12-31 12:59:59 +02:00",
            "1999-12-31 12:59:59 UTC+02:00",
            "1999-12-31 12:59:59 America/Porto_Velho",
    }) {
        TemporalAccessor parsed = DATE_TIME.parse(
                text ,
                (temporal) -> {
                    // see if there is an offset or tz
                    final ZoneId zoneOrOffset = temporal.query( TemporalQueries.zone() );
                    if ( zoneOrOffset != null ) {
                        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.from( temporal );
                        // EDIT: call normalized() to convert a ZoneId
                        // with constant offset, e.g., UTC+02:00, to ZoneOffset
                        if (zoneOrOffset.normalized() instanceof ZoneOffset) {
                            return zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
                        } else {
                            return zdt;
                        }
                    }

                    // otherwise it's a LocalDateTime
                    return LocalDateTime.from( temporal );
                }
        );

        System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%-30s %s%n", parsed.getClass(), parsed);
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> class java.time.LocalDateTime  1999-12-31T12:59:59
> class java.time.OffsetDateTime 1999-12-31T12:59:59+02:00
> class java.time.OffsetDateTime 1999-12-31T12:59:59+02:00
> class java.time.ZonedDateTime  1999-12-31T12:59:59-04:00[America/Porto_Velho]
> ```

### Simpler way for Java 9 and later

You were working too hard. Using `DateTimeFormatter.parseBest()` ought to have done your job in Java 8 and does work in Java 9 and later.

```
    String text = "1999-12-31 12:59:59 +02:00";

    TemporalAccessor parsed = DATE_TIME.parseBest(text,
            OffsetDateTime::from, ZonedDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from);

    System.out.println(parsed.getClass());
    System.out.println(parsed);
```

Output on Java 9:

> ```
> class java.time.OffsetDateTime
> 1999-12-31T12:59:59+02:00
> ```

EDIT: This way doesn’t make an `OFfsetDateTime` out of a string with `UTC+02:00` as time zone, though.

Comment: `#parseBest` worked great, although I do see slightly different behavior than you stated with Java 8 where it never returns an `OffsetDateTime`.  I always get either a `LocalDateTime` or a `ZonedDateTime`.  E.g. for the value `"1999-12-31 12:59:59 +02:00"` I get back a `ZonedDateTime` with zone-id (`ZonedDateTime#getZone`) of `"+02:00"`.  In general, that's actually fine for me - I am generally interested in ZonedDateTime as that's the more "persistence ready" format, although I'm interested to see the ramifications.  Thanks again Ole!

Comment: That seems to agree with my observations. I put it under *Simpler way for Java 9 and later* on purpose,. Thanks for reporting back (again).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this was actually a bug in Java 8. If you store the value of `DateTimeFormatter#parse` in a `Temporal` variable and print its `getClass()`, you receive the following when compiling and running with Java 8:

```
class java.time.ZonedDateTime
```

However, when compiling and running with Java 11, the output is what you expect:

```
class java.time.OffsetDateTime
```

I'm going to search around for the specific bug report and edit this answer if I manage to find it. That way, we can determine the cause of the bug as well as the version of Java it was fixed in.

Comment: Your answer got me on the "right path".  I almost have it working using Java 8, although for some reason JDK decided to make `ZoneRegion` non-public.  In some cases (UTC+02:00 e.g.) the zone is returned as a `ZoneRegion`.  In other cases, when `ZoneOffset` is used for the `ZoneId` I can make this work using instanceof.  But since `ZoneRegion` is non-public I cannot make that work (without crappy reflection, ofc)

Comment: @SteveEbersole I see. Is upgrading to Java 9+ not an option?

Comment: Well this is for use inside of Hibernate (I am re-working temporal literal support in query).  Unfortunately we still baseline on Java 8, so I need to support that.  And  even worse in fact I need to support it on 8 and 9+ :(

Comment: I didn’t readily find it in the [Java Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/) either. I’m convinced it must be there somewhere.